# Which iPhone UI Element is the Mail using?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I create the textfield that can accept image and text like the mail apps does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The composition view of Mail is a customized implementation of `UIWebDocumentView` (which also powers `UIWebView` and `UITextView`).

To create a text view that accepts images, you need to reconstruct the rendering and event handling mechanism yourself to abide to AppStore rules.